# RxJava2 - range() vs interval()

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I am trying to understand the `Hot Observable` and `Hot Flowable` using `Observable.range(1,1000).publish()`  and `Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish()`.

1. When I use `range()` instead of `interval()` to create an Observable/Flowable there is no need to pause the Thread in order to achieve the main Thread to wait for a while. `Main()` is not exiting until the range is complete. The same is not happening for `interval()` function.
2. Also, when I use `range()` instead of `interval()` to create an Observable/Flowable I have to subscribe Observer/Subscriber first before the `connect()` or else no items are received. Using the `interval()` everything works as I expect.

Could someone explain why this is happening? Is it the implementation of the `range()` or is it me that I don't understand something?

You can see the examples for Observable/Observer [here](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/KotlinReactiveExamples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/observableObserverSubject/ObservableHot.kt) and for Flowable/Subscriber [here](https://github.com/BILLyTheLiTTle/KotlinReactiveExamples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/backpressureFlowables/FlowableHot.kt).

Comment: There is a huge difference between `range` and `interval` that's why you get so much different results

Comment: @OmarMainegra I could understand that but I would like to have an explanation. This comment does not help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `range()` operator is cold and emits all of its items as soon as it can. If no back pressure is exerted, all items will be emitted in the first few microseconds.

The `interval()` operator is cold and emits its items one by one over time; the first item is emitted after the defined interval. If you subscribe in the main thread, and your main program exits, you will see no results from the `interval()` operator because enough time has not passed. This means you either have to block on the observer chain or provide an external means of waiting for the results you want.

Comment: Speaking for `Flowable` and `range()` shouldn't have  backpressure-awareness be default? I believe that the `Flowable` has by default backpressure-awareness and that it should wait around the 125 emitted items. If it waits for the first `Subscriber` to catch up with the `Flowable` why the second `Subscriber` receives nothing? First `Subscriber` needs a lot of time to catch up with the emitted items.

Comment: `Flowable` operators **are** back pressure-aware. However, if you don't apply back pressure, they will emit until you do. `Subscriber` will process the results of each emission in a few microseconds, unless you are doing some other significant processing. In any case, the `interval()` operator won't emit its first value for 0.5 seconds